# Bootstrap 4 navbar, with dropdowns, and responsive template?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

For B3 there are tonnes of templates of a top navbar, with drop down menus. As the screen size gets small, the menu collapses to the 3-bar button, and the menus become accordion menus.

Are there any examples or templates that do this using Bootstrap 4? The responsive examples I have have found collapse the menu, and show the 3-bar button, but the menus don't become accordion menus. There are also many drop down examples for BS4, but not of them on responsive.

Do I just have to hide the whole navbar when the screen gets small and reveal an accordian with all the same options? This seems like a lot more work than BS3.

Comment: Also read [
Bootstrap 4’s responsive navbars](http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/bootstrap-4s-responsive-navbars/) about navbar dropdowns and justified navbar items. See also https://github.com/bassjobsen/responsive-navbar-dropdowns for an example of navbar dropdown menus.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this would be to simply add a media query to your custom CSS that targets the screen size where the navigation is collapsed, then style your elements any way you like:

```css
@media (max-width: 544px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    display:none;
  }
  .navbar-nav .nav-item {
    float:none;
  }
  .navbar-nav .nav-item + .nav-item{
    margin-left:0;
  }
}
```

Here's a [simple example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWMYPj). Not very sophisticated but it should illustrate the point.